# Automator PDF actions

Tags: automator, pdf

When using the Automator PDF action "PDF to images" any annotations made to a PDF using preview are not converted as part of the output images. The base images are there but the annotations are not rendered.

Any solutions on this?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this with the following workflow, selecting the Legal Notices.pdf from Photoshop CC as my sample, and it worked fine, keeping all annotations on the PDF.

[image]

One thing to note that may be causing the problem is that the PDF is not saved. When adding annotations to a PDF, don't forget to save the PDF before running the workflow. If Preview states that the PDF has been edited, don't forget to save.

[image]